# Why is should.be.type() failing with "TypeError: (intermediate value).should.be.type is not a function"

Tags: should.js

I do not understand why the following test is failing with the error:

> TypeError: (intermediate value).should.be.type is not a function

```
describe('#Option object', function() {
    it('returns value as whatever type was passed to the constructor', function() {
        var o = function() {
            this.getValue = function() {
                return new Date();
            }
        };

        var i = new o();
        i.getValue().should.be.type('Date');
    })
});
```

I've read [most] of the [Should.js documentation](http://shouldjs.github.io) but I must be missing something. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually only one thing wrong. You read not should.js docs, but unit.js docs - it is not related to should.js at all.
Correct [link](http://shouldjs.github.io/).
Correct code will be:

```
i.getValue().should.be.instanceOf(Date);
```

or

```
i.getValue().should.be.Date();
```